# Unable to connect to ABB Freelance OPC Server [No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))]

Tags: .net, windows, com, dcom, opc

I have a problem in my OPC client application using `OPC NET API 2.00`, so when I want to connect to ABB Freelance OPC Server, it throws an exception when calling `Opc.Server.Connect(Opc.ConnectData)` method.

Exception:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to
>   interface type 'OpcRcw.Comn.IOPCServerList2'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{9DD0B56C-AD9E-43EE-8305-487F3188BF7A}' failed due to the
>   following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

May be Problem relates to `IOPCServerList2` interface:

```
#region Assembly OpcRcw.Comn.dll, v1.10.2.0
// C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\OpcRcw.Comn\1.10.2.0__9a40e993cbface53\OpcRcw.Comn.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace OpcRcw.Comn
{
    [Guid("9DD0B56C-AD9E-43EE-8305-487F3188BF7A")]
    [InterfaceType(1)]
    public interface IOPCServerList2
    {
        void CLSIDFromProgID(string szProgId, out Guid clsid);
        void EnumClassesOfCategories(int cImplemented, Guid[] rgcatidImpl, int cRequired, Guid[] rgcatidReq, out IOPCEnumGUID ppenumClsid);
        void GetClassDetails(ref Guid clsid, out string ppszProgID, out string ppszUserType, out string ppszVerIndProgID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IOPCCServerList2 is part of the OPCEnum service, not part of the server itself.

If you are connecting from remote, your application is accessing the OPCEnum service that is running at the same computer as the server.

IOPCCServerList2 is the new version of IOPCCServerList and most probable is that the version of OPCEnum service that is installed with ABB Freelance is too old.

You can update the OPCEnum service by installing the latest OPC Core Components that is available from the [OPC Foundation website](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/developer-kits-classic).

Comment: Yes, That's the point of my question, but for your answer, we can't install or update any software on the OPC server station, we have plant restrictions to do it.

Comment: Then you will need to avoid using OPCEnum or modify the .NET API so that it will use IOPCServerList instead of IOPCServerList2. You may be able to avoid it by using the CLSID of the server instead of the ProgID. But I am not 100% certain of the .NET API.

Comment: Thanks Jouni Aro, in order of ignoring side effects, `IOPCServerList2` is an internal interface that I can't change it to use `IOPCServerList`, we have solved the problem in changeing OPC API from .NET API to another Python based API.

Answer (score 0):

E_NOINTERFACE here is a generic COM error (not so useful to indicate the real problem).

Check:

- On the client: "OPC Core components redistributable" and RCWs mergemodule installed?
- On the client: firewall settings?
- On the server: dcom settings for the abb opc server is correct?

Just looking in the source code of IOPCCServerList2, my IOPCServerList2 has different version than yours.
My guess that you try to use the old merge modules/api designed for OPC DA 1.0 (which a very old and obsolate opc standards), most opc server expect OPC DA 2.0 client connections.

Here is mine:

```
#region Assembly OpcComRcw, Version=2.0.105.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9a40e993cbface53
// C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\OpcComRcw\2.0.105.1__9a40e993cbface53\OpcComRcw.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace OpcRcw.Comn
{
    [Guid( "9DD0B56C-AD9E-43ee-8305-487F3188BF7A" )]
    [InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
    public interface IOPCServerList2
    {
        void CLSIDFromProgID( string szProgId, out Guid clsid );
        void EnumClassesOfCategories( int cImplemented, Guid[ ] rgcatidImpl, int cRequired, Guid[ ] rgcatidReq, out IOPCEnumGUID ppenumClsid );
        void GetClassDetails( ref Guid clsid, out string ppszProgID, out string ppszUserType, out string ppszVerIndProgID );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, all of those works as expected when connect to another OPC Server brands like Yokogawa or Matrikon, but not working for ABB OPC Server.

Comment: Have you some opc test client to try connecting?

Comment: Yes, Matrikon and some of other commercial opc clients can connect and read data, but the .Net API failed to connect.

Comment: Please check you opc .net api and merge modules version. You may need to use OPC DA 2.0 version.

Comment: my OPC Net API version is 2.0 and Core Componenets version is 3.0 and OPC DA version is 1.1

Comment: API upgrade is not a solution, because of the OPC Server build date, ABB FreelanceOPC is very old and maybe downgrading is a solution, Maybe :)

Comment: You only need to update your OPC client API to use OPC DA 2.0. You don't need to update anything on the ABB Freelanc OPC server machine. I'm sure that your ABB OPC server supports OPC DA 2.0.